# BeautifulSoup not returning full HTML

Tags: html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Getting started in BeautifulSoup and running into a problem. Running:

```
# Web Scraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('page.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup('html_file', 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

returns this:

```
<html><body><p>html_file</p></body></html>
```

The problem is, the file itself has a lot more going on. It's an HTML example file in the same directory. So why is it only returning this?

Thanks for any insight.

Edit: Here is the HTML file I'm parsing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>simple_light - a page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <div id="logo_text">
          <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
          <h1><a href="index.html">simple<span class="logo_colour">_light</span></a></h1>
          <h2>Simple. Contemporary. Website Template.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
          <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="examples.html">Examples</a></li>
          <li class="selected"><a href="page.html">A Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="another_page.html">Another Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>Latest News</h1>
        <h4>New Website Launched</h4>
        <h5>January 1st, 2010</h5>
        <p>2010 sees the redesign of our website. Take a look around and let us know what you think.<br /><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
        <h1>Useful Links</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
          <p>
            <input class="search" type="text" name="search_field" value="Enter keywords....." />
            <input name="search" type="image" style="border: 0; margin: 0 0 -9px 5px;" src="style/search.png" alt="Search" title="Search" />
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <h1>A Page</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="examples.html">Examples</a> | <a href="page.html">A Page</a> | <a href="another_page.html">Another Page</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></p>
      <p>Copyright &copy; simple_light | <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">HTML5</a> | <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a> | <a href="http://www.html5webtemplates.co.uk">design from HTML5webtemplates.co.uk</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

Not letting me post this without adding more text so ignore this.

Comment: Hmm... not familiar with the concept, but like I said, it's an HTML document I downloaded to the same directory, so I'm not parsing through a real website yet, just a downloaded template. I just appended the HTML file for reference.

Comment: Works as expected for me. I noticed a typo: `BeautifulSoup('html_file', 'lxml')` should be `BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')`

Comment: Oh wow, it was the typo! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @ggloren for pointing out my typo:

```
BeautifulSoup('html_file', 'lxml')
```

should be

```
BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
```